# signed build installation failed on OnePlus One

Tags: android, failed-installation

I created a signed build of my application which is working fine in every device but fails to install in OnePlus One device with device error as `App not installed`. I tried to check the logcat and it resulted into `Installation error code: -7`. I looked for it on Google but found nothing helpful.

This happened when I changed the package name of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [this page](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#PackageManager.0INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK) for errorcodes.

> Installation return code: this is passed to the
>   IPackageInstallObserver by
>   installPackage(android.net.Uri,android.content.pm.IPackageInstallObserver,int,java.lang.String)
>   if a previously installed package of the same name has a different
>   signature than the new package (and the old package's data was not
>   removed).

Obviously, check the signatures. If it is your phone only, remove the application from your phone before installing the new apk.

Answer (score 0):

Please check sometimes in android devices if your have multiple users enabled.
Or guest account enabled then some of the times apps gets installed for all users.

Check as below

1. If app launcher is not showing app installed, then check under device settings->apps

And try to find app

2. If you find app listed in their tap to open app info page. Now open menu and select uninstall for all users.

Above steps will remove app from all users accounts. And then you would be able to install app again.